# Back-to-back PMSG based wind turbine

Tags: power-electronics, windturbine, renewable-energy

We have a PMSG based wind turbine with back-to-back converter. Now, the Permanent magnet provides a rotating magnetic field. So, how does the reactive power exchange happen between converter and grid?